# Issues with variables while moving a root module to a child module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
Terraform v1.5.7
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.20.0
```

My requirement is to convert my current tested (root) module into a child module. It creates asg, targets groups, listeners etc.,

I have this snippet of code which worked fine when it was used at a root module. I have the sns topic name variable defined in variables.tf and the actual name passed via an entry in variables.tfvars. However, when i tried to moved this to a root module I am getting erorr msg.

```
data "aws_sns_topic" "insights" {
  name = var.sns_topic_name
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_notification" "asg_sns" {
  group_names = [
    aws_autoscaling_group.this.name
  ]
  notifications = [
    "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE",
    "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCH_ERROR",
    "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE_ERROR",
  ]
  topic_arn = data.aws_sns_topic.insights.arn
}

 Error: Missing required argument
│ 
│   with module.asg.data.aws_sns_topic.insights,
│   on modules/asg/main.tf line 162, in data "aws_sns_topic" "insights":
│  162:   name = var.sns_topic_name
│ 
│ The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found.
```

As I have nearly 50+ variables in this module, so I do not want to pass all of them from the root module while calling the child module. I would like the child module to use the .tfvars values just as it did when it ran as a separate root module.

```
variable "sns_topic_name" {
  description = "SNS topic name for asg notifications on exceptions/errors"
  type        = string
  # default     = null
}
```

The default for topic name var is set to "null" and the actual name is set in .tfvars. If I do this, I get the above error. I don't want to set some valid value as 'default' bcos i would like all valid values to come from .tfvars and nothing from variables.tf. People usually review .tfvars while changing values for different environments and it is risky to have something come from var.tf. If I set some dummy text in the default, it tries to find that topic and errors out bcos it wont exist.

Any idea what I should attempt/change?

Also, for the below code which worked fine at a root module

```
locals {
  sg_prefix = var.subnet_type == "abc" ? var.sg_dmz_prefix : var.sg_app_internal_prefix
}
data "aws_security_groups" "insights" {
  filter {
    name   = "group-name"
    values = [local.sg_prefix]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "vpc-id"
    values = [data.aws_vpc.vpc.id]
  }
  tags = {
    ManagedBy = "XXXX"
  }
}
```

it gives this error because the default values are null and it is not taking values from .tfvars  I am guessing this is all due to how the 'data' source is computed for a child module.

```
Error: Null value found in list
│ 
│   with module.asg.data.aws_security_groups.insights,
│   on modules/asg/main.tf line 64, in data "aws_security_groups" "insights":
│   64: data "aws_security_groups" "insights" {
│ 
│ Null values are not allowed for this attribute value.
```

This is how I am calling the child module in the root:

```
module "asg" {
  source = "./modules/asg"
}
```

This is the folder structure (you can ingore terrafor.tf under asg, it's commented out inside)

```
|-main.tf
 |-.terraform
 | |-terraform.tfstate
 | |-modules
 | | |-modules.json
 | |-providers
 | | |-registry.terraform.io
 | | | |-hashicorp
 | | | | |-aws
 | | | | | |-5.20.0
 | | | | | | |-linux_amd64
 | | | | | | | |-terraform-provider-aws_v5.20.0_x5
 |-modules
 | |-asg
 | | |-main.tf
 | | |-outputs.tf
 | | |-terraform.tf
 | | |-terraform.tfvars
 | | |-init-rhel.sh
 | | |-variables.tf
 |-variables.tf
 |-terraform.tfvars
 |-.terraform.lock.hcl
```

I see that the issue applies to all variables. When 'asg' was a root module I had all variables' default set to null, and values provided in .tfvars. Looks like something changes when we shift the whole folder into a module and try to invoke from root.

Comment: How are you calling the module?

Comment: Hi @MarkoE, I added it in the main post (at the bottom) for a friendlier view. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a problem to set all variables of child module from root module?

Let's say that I have this example code:

```
.
├── main.tf
├── module
│   ├── print.tf
│   └── var.tf
└── terraform.tfvars
```

where

- `main.tf`:

```
variable external_example_var {
  description = "This variable is set inside terraform.tfvars"
}

module "test" {
  source = "./module"
  example_var = var.external_example_var
}

output "we_did_it" {
  value = module.test.variable_value_is
}
```

- `module/print.tf`

```
output "variable_value_is" {
  value = var.example_var
}
```

- `module/var.tf`

```
variable "example_var" {
  type = string
  description = "This variable must be set"
}
```

- `terraform.tfvars`

```
external_example_var = "example"
```

And output result of `terraform apply` is:

```
Outputs:

we_did_it = "example"
```

Here is module's `example_var` is passed from root as `external_example_var`. And here are no defaults inside `*.tf` at all. All necessary variables should be passed is taken from `terraform.tfvars`. You don't need to set *values* inside `*.tf` files, but variable names should be defined. And that is really good practice. If someone will try to reuse your module he will be able to explicitly check what variable names should be set inside module to be able run correctly. Hiding all variable definitions inside `tfvars` file will make it implicit.

> People usually review .tfvars

Yes. In my example all variable values stored inside `.tfvars` only. But variable names are defined inside module. And that is correct, because terraform will be able to check in runtime if all variables has been set correctly (if review didn't help to find mistake)

---

In other way, if you have many variables and their names always changing it will be easier to set one big and flexible `object`-like variable `parameters` that will be a dictionary with dynamic keys:

- `module/var.tf`

```
variable "example_var" {
  type = map
  description = "This variable must be set"
}
```

- `main.tf`

```
variable free_parameters {
  description = "Any parameters stored as key->value set"
}

module "test" {
  source = "./module"
  example_var = var.free_parameters
}

output "we_did_it" {
  value = module.test.variable_value_is["free_key"]
}
```

- `terraform.tfvars`

```
free_parameters = {"free_key": "example"}
```

Comment: First up, thanks a bunch for going well out of your way to put such an elaborate example which helped. I implemented your suggestion of moving .tfvars to root and added 50+ statements of var1 = var.var1 etc., That did the trick. Although, I wonder why TF didn't make it work with .tfvars at child module level itself. :)  Sometime I will try out the other option you suggsted too. Thank you once again!

Comment: `why TF didn't make it work with .tfvars at child module level itself` → That is my own point of view and I'm not sure that is 100% correct, but `module` in terraform is a reusable unit. If developers that using your module will have to manually create extra `terraform.tfvars` inside module folder, it will be really implicit and inconvenient. It is matter of application design. Passing all necessary variables from runtime to internal module sounds logically correct for me. If you have not necessary variables, then `default` may be set for them to be able avoid passing of all variables

Answer (score 0):

> As I have nearly 50+ variables in this module, so I do not want to pass all of them from the root module while calling the child module. I would like the child module to use the .tfvars values just as it did when it ran as a separate root module.

Unfortunately that is not something Terraform supports. You will have to explicitly pass all the values from your tfvars into your module via the module declaration.

The values in tfvars only set variables at the root level. Child modules *never* inherit variables from their parent or root module.

Comment: I was hoping that all the variables defined at the child level itself will suffice and i dont have to define or pass bulk of them from root. My intent is to only send in a few key parameters if needed but bulk of what is needed is already at the child module level.

Comment: If the child module's variables all have defaults that work, and you only want to override a few of those defaults from the root level, then those are the only things you need to pass from the root to the child module. But you would have to define those as `default` values in the child module `var` declarations. Those default values won't be picked up in the child module from the `terraform.tfvars` file.